# how to process unico uv2100 .tst file format?

Tags: gratis

I recieved my sample's visible spectrum data from a lab which uses unico uv2100 spectrophotometer in .tst format. I need to process this raw data. I can write some software for it as the data is visible in notepad but i was wondering if a free software is available for it.

I searched the web but couldnt find a free one.
Thanks.